# Unidentifiable processes under Redhat Linux

Tags: linux, redhat, process, linux-kernel

Upon issuing a `ps ax` command on a server I see the following processes that I can't identify. Googling them yields nothing useful. Does anybody know what these are or how I would track them down?

The system is a virtual machine running on VMware. I'm not sure what version as I don't control the infrastructure but I have asked if any VM snapshots or backups are taking place and they have said no.

System is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
Kernel is 2.6.18-164.el5

The system has been rebooted but these processes remain.

```
 7158 ?        S<     0:00 [WRITE_COW_THR0]
 7159 ?        S<     0:00 [ISSUE_WR_THR0]
 7160 ?        S<     0:00 [SNAP_R_THR0]
 7161 ?        S<     0:00 [WRITE_COW_THR1]
 7162 ?        S<     0:00 [ISSUE_WR_THR1]
 7163 ?        S<     0:00 [SNAP_R_THR1]
 7164 ?        S<     0:00 [WRITE_COW_THR2]
 7165 ?        S<     0:00 [ISSUE_WR_THR2]
 7166 ?        S<     0:00 [SNAP_R_THR2]
 7167 ?        S<     0:00 [WRITE_COW_THR3]
 7168 ?        S<     0:00 [ISSUE_WR_THR3]
 7169 ?        S<     0:00 [SNAP_R_THR3]
```

Comment: They look like kernel threads.

Comment: Any chance this server runs an Oracle 12c DB with Snap Clone running?

Comment: It runs databases (Progress), not Oracle. I don't believe the Progress databases do any snapshotting / cloning. If they do, it would be very unusual.

Comment: `ls -l /proc/7158/exe`

Comment: exe is an invalid symlink. When I list the /proc/7158 folder, I see the following: http://pastebin.com/DXH8BH4d

Answer (score 3):

These look like [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) (COW) kernel threads possible related to a filesystem snapshotting solution. Do you have something like [R1Soft Hot-Copy](http://www.r1soft.com/free-tool-linux-hot-copy) or LVM snapshots active? Any other backup software?

Please provide a pastebin of a full process listing.

Comment: I agree. It does look like a kernel thread performing a snapshot but the company running the VMware host insists it is not. We are not running any snapshotting within the machine itself. I have put up the pastebin but have admittedly removed the database processes as they could identify the client. We run these databases on many servers and have never seen these processes anywhere else. http://pastebin.com/YdpXbak6

Comment: Please post the output of `df -h` and `lvdisplay`.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the requested commands. http://pastebin.com/yVYrNYGy